# How do i pass a multidimensional array to my c# web api

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I have a very large array that looks like this:

[image: array in my console]

So in this case it consist of 85 arrays with 473 counts of data in each array.

I am currently passing this array to a web api to then process this data, this is how i do it:

```
        function DeepDataProcess(array, callback) {
            console.log(array[0]);
            console.log(array);

            var promise = HttpRequestFactory.Go({
               url: 'api/ImportData/PostDataProcessing',
               method: 'POST',
               data: array[0] // this is the first index in the array I want to send the full array.
            });

        promise.then(function (response) { callback(response); }).catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });
    }
```

as you can tell in my javascript i am only passing one array because when i try to send the full array my web api says my parameter is null. I also don't want to call my web api 85 times to get the full array in there, note: i know this array is a multidimensional array.

and below is my web api (c#):

```
    [Route("PostDataProcessing")]//I have tried adding string[,] as the parameter  
    public IHttpActionResult PostDataProcessing(string[] array) //so that it can accept a multidimensional array but I still get a null value
    {
        var response = setDataProcessorService().DeepDataProcess(array);

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

when i send the full array my web api says my parameter array is empty.

How do I make my  c# web api accept a multidimensional array as its parameter?

Below is the request I am making:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how `HttpRequestFactory` works but you probably have to set your `content-type` to `application/json` and stringify your array

Comment: @sklingler93 i will post a picture of my request, the data is being transferred just fine

Comment: @sklingler93 I have added to request from chrome so you can see the data is being sent just fine. HttpRequestFactory is just a factory I created to handle my http requests